# Event declaration with assignment to empty delegate

Tags: c#

I have question on a piece of code I often stumble across online. For example

```
  public static event Action<Foo> foo = delegate{  };
```

I got the left hand side of the declaration. But the right hand side is confusing. What is the point in assigning the event to a delegate with empty parenthesis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: in modern versions of C#, the recommended pattern to use is to leave it as null and use the `?.` operator:

```
event Action<Foo> foo; // leave it as null as the default
// ...
foo?.(new Foo());
```

---

In older versions of C#, the reason for this pattern could be that the default value of an `event` field is `null`. This requires the use of a null-check every-time you want to raise the event - calling `foo()` on an uninitialised `event` field would result in a `NullReferenceException`. It's more convenient to just give it a sensible default value like a no-op, that way you can raise the event directly without having to use a wrapper method or anything.

Answer (score 4):

The default value of a delegate member is `null`, so if you don't assign anything to it, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` when you attempt to call it.  You can easily see how this could be a problem: imagine if you had to subscribe to `OnKeyDown` on *every* control!

Handily, events in the standard library are *guarded*, which does an equivalent thing:

```
Event handler = OnClick
if (handler != null)
    handler(this, new EventArgs());
```

This is the form I'd recommend, as - to me anyway - it looks cleaner.  Also, note the use of a local variable.  It is legal to write it as

```
if(OnClick != null) OnClick(this, new EventArgs());
```

but that isn't threadsafe, as the listener to OnClick could unsubscribe between the null check and the call.